# Vue js data not displaying on template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having a hard time understanding why I can't display what is returned by `data`.

From the code below, `{{userId}}`, `{{test}}` do not get printed but everything else does. For example the texts `User with id`, `test:`, `Public profile of user` and the content of `{{$route.params.used_id}}`.

Why is that the case and what do I need to do to fix this?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>User with id {{userId}}</h1>
    <h1>test: {{test}}</h1>
    <h1>{{user_id}}</h1>
    <p>Public profile of user</p>
    <p>{{$route.params.user_id}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["user_id"],
  data: function() {
    return {
        //id is name of the dynamic segment we created in router
      userId: this.$route.params.user_id,
      test: "test"
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

Errors from console:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "userId" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

[Vue warn]: Property or method "test" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

Comment: Any errors in console ?

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of looking at that, let me edit my post

Comment: you should to assign `userId` in your `mounted()` function

Comment: @Nipun Jain, the solution that you posted and removed worked for me.

Comment: I think you downvoted that ..

Comment: Nope, it wasn't me

Comment: Can you accept this answer if it resolved your issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your data property like this

```
data () {
    return {
        //id is name of the dynamic segment we created in router
      userId: this.$route.params.user_id,
      test: "test"
    }
  }
```

As you are using `this` inside `data`

Answer (score 2):

You mustn't use this way:

```
data: function() {
  return {
    userId: this.$route.params.user_id,
    test: "test"
  };
}
```

Because is a closure. Closures have access the scope of outer function. Please see this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

The correct way is that:

```
data() {
  return {
    userId: this.$route.params.user_id,
    test: "test"
  };
}
```

Because is a method and can access `this` variable.